# How can I properly read a line while I convert it into pig latin?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I got and I don't know why Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException...I want to create a menu and transform a sentence inputed from the user into pig latin . How I can read a line properly without getting that exception ?

```
public class Main {

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String options = "1.Print the options\n2.Transform a sentence into PIG latin\n" +
                "3.quit";
        System.out.println(options);
        boolean quit = false;

        while (!quit) {
           int choice = scanner.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println(options);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    encryptIntoPigLatin();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void encryptIntoPigLatin() {
        System.out.println("Please enter the sentence: ");
        String sentence = "";

        sentence = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println(sentence);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sentence);
    }

    private static void printLatinWord(String s) {
        String firstLetter = s.substring(0, 1);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        result.append(s.substring(1) + firstLetter + "ay");
        System.out.println(result.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: What line is it saying the error is on

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 Scanners instances, one for the menu and the other one for the sentence

```
private static Scanner scannerMenu = new Scanner(System.in);
private static Scanner scannerSentence = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Your problem is that you are using the same scanner for the menu and the sentence. Keep in mind the the scanner you are using in the `encryptIntoPigLatin()` method is also nested in the while loop.